# Oracle Apex 21 looking for sample data for customer sample app

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex

I have started using and learning APEX 21.2. It seems in previous version there was a sample database application that included sample data when installed. In 21.2 there is no such sample application, there is howeve, a starter customers app that installs with no data. Are there any sample datasets for the customers app, which would be very helpful for tutorial purposes?

Comment: Apex 22.1 was released this week, it includes a new data generator feature. I've not tried it out yet but I have looked at some of the code and it looks like it will give you exactly what you're after if you can do the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the sample schemas? They're distributed with Oracle, but you need to run a script to install them: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC00001

The Apex sample apps are changing how they're distributed. I think they're no longer included as Packaged Applications, but you can get them on Github. https://oracle.github.io/apex/

Answer (score 0):

Starting with APEX 21.1, Productivity and Sample Applications are no longer distributed with the product. Instead, a collection of Starter Applications, Sample Applications, and Sample Plug-Ins will be available for download online, from GitHub.
Those can now be found here: https://oracle.github.io/apex/

Although the 22.1 release made this easier as you can query the Github catalog and install applications directly.

There are also sample dataset you can install. Go in SQL Workshop -> Utilities -> Sample Datasets.

Note that the sample application will install the required dataset automatically.